# How do I import my iPhone Mail imap account settings to my Macbook Mail client?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

How do I import my iPhone Mail IMAP account settings to my Macbook Mail client? Do I have to enter them manually?

Answer (score 0):

[You can't do this.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8632691) You will have to enter the IMAP details by hand.